# Prevent clipping of bubbles centered near boundaries in a bubble chart with log scale axis and sqrt scale for bubble size?

Tags: d3.js

What would be a good algorithm to prevent clipping of bubbles centered near boundaries in a bubble chart with log scale x and y axis and sqrt scale for bubble size ?
For example if the max bubble radius is 40 px, how can i ensure that the bubble chart leaves enough space such that bubbles near chart boundaries are not cut off ?

Comment: Use a `range()` that's 40px smaller than the view area and translate everything 20px.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i think an easy way to address this is to first create the axis (say varAxis) using :
domain = [minDomainValue, maxDomainValue]
range = [minRangeValue + bubbleRadius, maxRangeValue - bubbleRadius ]
And then reset the axis using :
domain = [varAxis.invert(minRangeValue), varAxis.invert(maxRangeValue)]
range = [minRangeValue, maxRangeValue ]